# Error: The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts

Tags: php, api, paypal, response

I have a problem with one specific paypal payment. Here you can find the summary of the customer journey:

1. Added one item £5.59
2. Applied coupon code which fixes total amount to £0.01.
   Total: £0.01
3. Pay with paypal express.

The payment does not go through and i am getting this error message:

```
Error: The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts
```

I am breaking down all response here:

```
paypal_error: 'We were not able to complete your order at this time'

SUCCESSPAGEREDIRECTREQUESTED: 'false'
ACK: 'Success'
VERSION: '123.0'
L_ERRORCODE0: '10413'
L_SHORTMESSAGE0: 'Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.'
L_LONGMESSAGE0: 'The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.'
L_SEVERITYCODE0: 'Error'
BILLINGAGREEMENTACCEPTEDSTATUS: '0'
CHECKOUTSTATUS: 'PaymentActionNotInitiated'

PAYERSTATUS: 'verified'

ADDRESSID: 'PayPal'
ADDRESSSTATUS: 'Confirmed'
CURRENCYCODE: 'GBP'
AMT: '0.01'
ITEMAMT: '0.01'
SHIPPINGAMT: '0.00'
HANDLINGAMT: '0.00'
TAXAMT: '0.01'
INSURANCEAMT: '0.00'
SHIPDISCAMT: '0.00'
INSURANCEOPTIONOFFERED: 'false'
L_NUMBER1: '/* coupon code writing here */'
L_QTY0: '1'
L_QTY1: '1'
L_TAXAMT0: '0.92'
L_TAXAMT1: '-0.91'
L_AMT0: '4.57'
L_AMT1: '-4.57'
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE: 'GBP'
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT: '0.01'
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT: '0.01'
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT: '0.00'
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT: '0.00'
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT: '0.01'
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT: '0.00'
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT: '0.00'

PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEOPTIONOFFERED: 'false'
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ADDRESSSTATUS: 'Confirmed'
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1: 'Coupon describtion writing here'
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER1:'/* coupon code writing here */'
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0: '1'
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1: '1'
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT0: '0.92'
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT1: '-0.91'
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0: '4.57'
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1: '-4.57'
PAYMENTREQUESTINFO_0_ERRORCODE: '0'
payment_cost: '0.01'
```

Does anyone work out problem ? Because it seems calculations are correct and there is no missing parameter.

Answer (score 2):

```
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT: '0.01'
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT: '0.00'
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT: '0.00'
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT: '0.01'
```

These do not add up to the total `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT: '0.01'`